Can quadratic form be related to integration?
Suppose we have a smooth function $f$ which is defined on $[0,1]$. We pick $n$ points $t_1,\dots, t_n\in[0,1]$ and have the vector $(f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))^T\in R^n$. We also have a strictly positive definite matrix $A\in R^{n\times n}$, and the trace of $A$ is 1 (the reason for this trace condition is that I hope to make things bounded).
I wonder is it possible to connect the quadratic form $(f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n)) A (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))^T$ to some integration like $\int_0^T f(t)^2\omega(t) dt$, where $\omega(t)$ is some function. I hope to give some error bound for $\vert (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n)) A (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))^T - \int_0^T f(t)^2\omega(t) dt\vert$ as $n$ increases.
However I didn't find any materials connecting a quadratic form to some bivariate integration. I guess such kind of problem may have something to do with the spectral properties of the matrix $A$. Could someone please give me some advice to find related materials/topics?
Edit:
Thanks for all your help!
Now what if I want to connect the quadratic form $(f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n)) A (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))^T$ to bivariate integration like $\int_0^T \int_0^T f(t) f(s)\omega(t,s) dt ds$, where $\omega(t,s)$ is some bivariate function. I hope to give some error bound for $\vert (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n)) A (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))^T - \int_0^T \int_0^T f(t) f(s)\omega(t,s) dt ds\vert$ as $n$ increases?

How does $A$ behave as $n$ increases?

@sudeep5221 Hi, I don't have other conditions for A, only suppose it's positive definite with trace 1.

The quadratic form can be expressed like
$$\mathbf f\mathbf A\mathbf f^\top=\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}f(t_i)f(t_j)$$
We can treat the integral as a summation using Riemann's definition in order to compare it to the form:
$$\int_0^Tf^2(t)\omega(t)\,\mathrm dt\simeq\frac{T}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}\omega(t_i^{\ast})f(t_i^{\ast})f(t_i^{\ast}),$$
where
$$\left\{t_i^{\ast}=t_i\left|t_i\in\left[(i-1)\dfrac{T}{n},i\dfrac{T}{n}\right.\right]\right\}$$
Obviously the integral and summation are equal in the case where $n\to\infty$. Also, note that there's no $j$, in fact, $j=i$, and so, it's like $\omega(t_i^{\ast})\sim A_{ii}$.
In brief, for a diagonal matrix $\mathbf A$ (maybe it could be diagonalized),
$$\int_0^Tf^2(t)\omega(t)\,\mathrm dt\simeq\frac{T}{n}\mathbf f\mathbf A\mathbf f^\top,$$
where $\omega(t)$ would be a regression that would pass through each of the points $(t_i,A_{ii})_{i=1}^n$.
